# Como obter o tempo em segundos de uma data no formato string?

Tags: c++, datetime

Sei que a função `time(0)` me retorna os segundos desde o dia primeiro de janeiro de 1970, no caso o usuário entraria com uma data (dd-mm-aaaa ou em qualquer formato por motivo de limitação do sistema) e o sistema faria a verificação de qual data é mais antiga.

Há bibliotecas que trabalhem com isso? Qual seria a melhor maneira de passar uma data para o sistema para transforma-lo em segundos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe [esta struct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) que serve para manipular datas.

Acho que o que você deseja é algo desse tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm = {};  // inicializa com zeros
    int dia, mes, ano;

    scanf(" %2d-%2d-%4d", &dia, &mes, &ano);
    tm.tm_mday = dia;
    tm.tm_mon  = mes - 1;
    tm.tm_year = ano - 1900;

    time_t tempo = mktime(&tm);
    puts(asctime(&tm));
    printf("%d\n", tempo);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, exatamente isso, mt obrigado!